# Need for a tag to describe teaching/student evaluations?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently added the new tag 'student-evaluation' to the question [Is it appropriate to include additional materials in an academic job application?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/), but this was quickly removed. However, from what I could find, there are no tags describing this subject, even though such a tag should be relevant for many questions here on AcademiaSE (both current and future ones).

Searching the main site, 'evaluation + teaching' turns up [62 results](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=evaluation+%2B+teaching), and from scanning these the tag would clearly be relevant for many of them. The specific phrases '"teaching evaluations"' and '"student evaluations"' shows up 6 and 7 times respectively.

When adding the tag I initially chose between 'student-evaluation' and 'teaching-evaluation', and chose the former. However, either one would fit the purpose, and on a second thought the latter option might be more general (could encompass 'student-evaluation' but also other types of evaluations of teaching skills).

Do you think that there is a need for such a tag? From what I can see there seems to be a "research-bias" in the current tags, with relatively few tags that deal with the teaching side of academic activities.

Comment: Perhaps you can list all the questions you think would benefit from such a tag?

Comment: @CharlesMorisset Have added some background now.

Answer (score 1):

I think a fairer search is to limit yourself to questions and not questions and answers.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=evaluation+%2B+teaching+is%3Aquestion

Limiting the search to questions only gives 12 hits, some of which don't seem like they would be relevant for [teaching-evaluation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-evaluation). I could imagine in the future such a tag could be helpful, but until the questions are asked, I don't see a need for the tag.

As for the linked question, it doesn't seem to be about teaching evals.

Comment: The linked question is specifically asking about advice on whether to include results from student course evaluations to an academic application, i.e an evaluation of teaching. Did you read the question? I agree about the search results though, but still think that it is fairly obvious that such a tag would be useful, now and in the future. I'm pretty certain that I can find 10+ questions where this tag would be relevant, and at the moment there are a large number of tags with much fewer questions than that on AcademiaSE.

Answer (score 0):

We have [assessment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assessment), which Noble P. Abraham introduced in an edit to [a question of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3575/2700) a year ago. It currently has 5 questions, and I think it would be fitting for your questions.

Comment: That could work if the scope is expanded. However, all the current questions deal with the assessment of students, and the wiki says; "Queries related to assessment of students for skills, attitudes, knowledge etc.". Since the assessment of students is a quite separate thing from evaluations of teaching I would definately prefer a separate tag. Personally, I also doubt that the tag name "assessment" is the first thing that comes to mind when people are thinking about possible tags to add to questions that deal with teaching evaluations.